# Ubuntu for lenovo thinkpad Tablet 2 which one?

Tags: tablet

Ubuntu is already working on five of my laptops a 10+++ I would like to know which ubuntu can i install on my Lenovo Thinkpad Tablet 2 I dont want to make a mistake and would like to know first
                                                     Thanks
                                                    Great Job!
ps, I converted 10 people in less then a month
     to ubuntu 13.04

Comment: i got ubuntu (x64) installed and running just fine on my lenovo miix latop/tablet with the same 32bit UEFI, i just wrote out a big answer of how i did it, here's the link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/761355/lenovo-tablet-ubuntu-usb-installation/1000081#1000081

Answer (score 1):

The Tablet 2 supports only 32-bit UEFI 2.3.1 OS--so you are stuck with Windows 8 or WinPE only.

Source is:

https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-slate-tablets-Knowledge/How-to-get-to-a-BIOS-Boot-Menu-on-the-Tablet-2/ta-p/994207