# Lenovo Tablet - Ubuntu USB Installation

Tags: live-usb, bios

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on a Lenovo Yoga2 tablet and I have not been able to run the bootable USB drive with the installation files.

How can I do it? It's running Windows 10. I have tried mounting it with Rufus, but nothing happened after entering system select. The only option is Windows.

---

I'm trying to use the most up to date version and this process bricked the tablet at the OS select. I just need to get a working USB keyboard to get through that screen so no bother.

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you trying to install?

Comment: [Try this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu on Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro](http://askubuntu.com/questions/367963/ubuntu-on-lenovo-yoga-2-pro)

Answer (score 0):

Excuse my long long answer, it's just that I didn't find 1 successful answer or story of someone installing any linux OS onto a lenovo Miix 310 Tablet so I thought I should post it in detail here.

(This worked completely for me, but i have no idea how).

I had a similar problem with a Lenovo Miix 310, it's a hybrid pc/tablet with a UEFI type BIOS.

It wouldn't let me boot with a bootable USB and doesn't have a CD/DVD drive.

I tried partitioning the disk and installing Ubuntu on that disk from windows, but after much failed attempts it wouldn't let me in anyway resize the system partition, or extend the 1GB partition that I could delete and edit. I tried with every free disk partition software I could find. so I tried installing Lubuntu (smaller than 1GB) thinking it was small enough but I still couldn't install it from windows.

I couldn't use `gparted` because it had to be as bootable image with Windows and I didn't figure a way around that.

I then followed [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/484434/install-ubuntu-without-cd-and-usb-how), the top answer tells you how to do it, ignore the 1st half of the answer as that is for BIOS, follow the UEFI part.
that linked answer DID NOT WORK BUT it did successfully install the "rEFInd" (not `grub2`) boot menu entry.

When I tried to boot from that it would automatically bypass back to Windows.
(I don't know if that step was necessary or not, but that's what I did).

**CAUTION: THAT STEP MIGHT BE COMPLETELY IRREVERSIBLE and completely removes Windows.**

What worked for me then was I opened up a different free partition manager 
(not tenorshare this time) and I deleted the windows system partition altogether (as I have no interest in using Windows again or dualbooting)

Once I hit apply changes in the disk partition manager the screen turned black, after reboot it went to the rEFInd bootscreen and said there was nothing to boot or something like that.

Then I rebooted going into the UEFI BIOS settings (F2 or F12), I found the "Secure Boot" option and diabled it, then I went to "Exit saving changes".

On another computer I downloaded "etcher" for windows (cross platform software) and the `gparted` ISO image and I used etcher to made a bootable USB of `gparted`.

I rebooted my lenovo with my USB connected and it booted `gparted`, I used that to completely delete all partitons on my disk, I created a partition table in "GPT" format ("ms-dos" aka "MBR" would have probably worked but my hard disk had already been on GPT so I chose that).

Then I created a partition leaving 2GB left. I formatted the partition to "ext4" "primary". then I made the last 2GB into a partition formatted to "linux-swap".
I exited this and turned off the laptop.

I downloaded loads of versions of linux (various flavours of ubuntu, linuxmint and elementary OS).

With trial and error I went one by one through these different OSes. I used etcher to install them to my USB as bootable.

Ubuntu Unity, Xubuntu, Lubuntu, Kubuntu, Linuxmint Cinnamon, Linuxmint mate, LMDE had weird graphics that were hard to see and no wifi capabilities (which I needed considering no ethernet connection on laptop), some better than others.

Ubuntu GNOME, Ubuntu Budgie and Elementary OS booted up but went completely black after the startup logo.

Then by complete chance while using Ubuntu Budgie, after the screen went black for a few minutes I quickly pressed the power button and noticed the power indicator led turned off so I pressed it again and it came back on, then the screen flashed on and off (clearly with a desktop background, so I repeated this a few times until it stayed on) and that was that.

The wifi was working so I installed the OS, ticking the boxes to download content and install 3rd party stuff, etc. Then I downloaded software and did updates and rebooted.

It seemed to reboot fine, then the screen went black and unresponsive, but all I had to do was restart it. (power off and on quickly or just close the screen and open it again) and it went straight to login screen and works perfectly.

I have to do that everytime I boot it but it doesn't go black again after the first time until the next reboot.

Everything seems perfect, wifi, keyboard, touchscreen, internal speakers... I don't use bluetooth so I dont know about that.

The only issue (still pending!) is the headphones/external speaker does not work or even register being there.

Also, probably it being a tablet and all... every single OS had the screen sideways.

How I fixed this was by opening terminal and typing:

```
xrandr -o right
```

That fixed the rotation.

Then I went to settings>keyboard and made a keyboard shortcut onto 2 keys I never use, one being the command:

```
xrandr -o right
```

(Make the screen lanscape) and the other being:

```
xrandr -o normal
```

(Make it portrait).

Then I went to startup applications and added a start up command of

```
xrandr -o right
```

So that it would automatically orientate the display to lanscape upon booting up.

Comment: i think a lenovo yoga has the same wierd 32bit UEFI BIOS using RAID5 with a 64bit system as the lenovo miix.